# inList Validation error message is not showing

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have this validation code in Model, problem is this particular validation message is not showing though validation is occurring, when I am going to submit a form, I want to show error message below the field of difficulty. I am expecting your help, your help will be highly appreciated.

```
$validator
->add('difficulty',[
'valid'=>[
'rule' =>['inList',[1,2,3,4]],
'message' => __('work difficulty required'),
],
]) ;
return $validator
```

input.ctp

```
<tr>
<th>Work difficulty (*)</th>
<td>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('difficulty',
[
'type' => 'select',
'options'=>$difficulty_options,
'div'=>false, 
'label'=>false,
'empty' => 'Please select']
);
?>
</td>
</tr>>
```

in Controller.php

```
$difficulty_options = array(
"1"=>"難しすぎる (too difficult)",
"2" => "少し難しい（a little difficult)",
"3" => "簡単 （easy)",
"4" => "易しすぎる (too easy)"
);                          
$this->set('difficulty_options' , $difficulty_options);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: May you provide your input field code ?

Comment: @AlimonKarim, can you help me with this problem, I want "work difficulty required" printed for validation, if I left this valid empty, and click on save to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's very clear why you are not showing error message.

After validation, if any error occurs, by default cakephp generates an error div.

```
<div class="error-message">Your error message here</div>
```

Here in input field you have applied `'div'=>false`. For that reason this error-message div is not generating. Now you can solve it easily by using below code after your `difficulty` field.

```
echo $this->Form->error('difficulty', null, array('class' => 'error-message'));
```

Just add this line in your `<td>`

```
<td>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('difficulty',
[
'type' => 'select',
'options'=>$difficulty_options,
'div'=>false, 
'label'=>false,
'empty' => 'Please select']
);
?>
<?php  echo $this->Form->error('difficulty', null, array('class' => 'error-message')); ?>   // new line in here
</td>
```

Comment: @greg, i know its a silly question, and as I am new to cakePhp, can you please tell me where to put this code?                                                                          <div class="error-message">Your error message here</div>

Comment: the message is not showing. the message I have written in Validator, I want to show that message,but validation is happening, but not showing the error message. Do i need to change anything in controller or in validator..??

Comment: Did you add this line in your ctp file ? check it by this line 
<div class="error-message">Your error message here</div>

add this line after <td>

Comment: yeah, I have add your line in ctp file, but problem is the message is coming in form page before filling up any box.

Comment: please help me with the issue.